# Why is Peer-to-Peer programming a hard topic to obtain good research for?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic, p2p

After reading a bit more about how Gnutella and other P2P networks function, I wanted to start my own peer-to-peer system.  I went in thinking that I would find plenty of tutorials and language-agnostic guidelines which could be applied, however I was met with a vague simplistic overview.

I could only find very small, precise P2P code which didn't do much more than use client/server architecture on all users, which wasn't really what I was looking for.  I wanted something like Gnutella, but there doesn't seem to be any articles out in the open for joining the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write a basic Gnutella client in C# using Web Services and I think the class notes on the P2P stuff are still available [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~humphrey/cs451/ClassNotes/CS451_DisSys_0327.pdf) and [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~humphrey/cs451/ClassNotes/CS451_DisSys_0329.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 4981](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4981.txt), with its huge bibliography, could be a very good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better success researching Bittorrent, I believe that the creator has written some papers, and it seems others are as well.

[BitTyrant](http://bittyrant.cs.washington.edu/#papers)
[Bittorent.org, see the developers section](http://bittorrent.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what platform you are trying to use, but here is [a decent article on the subject for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188685.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [TheoryOrg Unofficial BitTorrent Specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) to be the best online source for Bittorrent information.  Also, the Monotorrent code is fairly simple and easy to understand.  There's also a project called "GCT" which implements JGroups style P2P for LAN/Multicast environments, and its code is similarly easy to understand (if a bit buggy).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read [Gnutella2](http://g2.trillinux.org/) and try to implement messaging. For reading conceptual material you can read Distributed Systems by Andrew Tannenbaum.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [JXTA](https://jxta.dev.java.net/).  It's intention was to be a generic, platform agnostic p2p framework, in contrast to other p2p implementations which are usually for a very specific purpose (such as Gnutella).

Don't be fooled by it's Java appearance, there are binding available for C/C++/C#, but the core protocols are implemented in XML which should translate to any language.

You can also download a free book [here](http://www.brendonwilson.com/projects/jxta-book/).